# Can I open multiple Gnucash account tabs at once?

Tags: gnucash, accounts

I have an investment parent account with more than a dozen subaccounts, one for each ticker symbol. When I go to reconcile a statement, I've been opening the subaccounts one at a time - i.e., I open ticker symbol ABC on the Accounts tab, and I'm automatically switched to the ABC tab. I switch back to Accounts, open symbol DEF, switch back, etc.

It gets tedious. Is there a way for me to open more than one subaccount tab at a time from Accounts?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what the precise problem to be solved is, but here's my 2 cents worth.

It's **definitely** possible to have multiple tabs representing different accounts open simultaneously in GnuCash.  As the question describes, registers for different accounts or sub-accounts are opened in turn from the main Accounts screen and each will open in its own tab in the GnuCash window.  If it's preferred to have the register open in its own new GnuCash window, this functionality can be selected in *GnuCash Preferences* (Edit Menu > Preferences).

Once the desired subaccounts are opened in separate tabs, you can easily jump from one tab to the next to reconcile them or edit transactions as desired.

If the question is "*Can I open multiple tabs representing multiple accounts **with a single mouse click**?*" - then no, I don't think that GnuCash is designed to do that.

Comment: I do eventually get all the tabs open and jump from one to the other, as you say. My question is whether there is a way, with the mouse or not, to request the opening of a bunch of tabs at the same time.